# Angular iterate through select options and set selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select set with States from JSON data:

```
<select name="ParentState" ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="s.StateID as s.StateCode for s in cStates | orderBy:'StateCode'">
    <option value="">Select State...</option>
</select>
```

and would like to set the selected state as the state returned for the logged in user but I'm entirely sure how to accomplish this in Angular.  Here's what I've tried and it isn't working.

```
angular.forEach($scope.cState, function (s) {
    if (s.StateCode == xParentState) {
        $scope.selectedState = s.StateCode;
    }
});
```

`xParent` is this state initials e.g. 'MI' for Michigan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngModel` is set to the `StateID` (as seen in your `ngOptions` - `value as text for object in array`) - so set that rather than `StateCode`

```
if (s.StateCode == xParentState) {
    $scope.selectedState = s.StateID;
}
```

Comment: I hate when I miss something so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [`ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

You're using the `select as label for value in array` expression here. So to set the ngModel, you will need to set the `StateID`.

Assuming you have an object like:

```
xParentState: {
    StateID: 1,
    StateCode: 'MI',
    StateName: 'Michigan'
}
```

Instead of iterating over the array of states, you can then set the value directly with `$scope.selectedState = xParentState.StateID` or you could use `ngInit` for setting it in the template (e.g. when the user reloads the page):

```
 <select ng-model="selectedState" ng-options="s.StateID as s.StateCode for s in cStates | orderBy:'StateCode'" ng-init="selectedState = xParentState.StateID">
     <option value="">Select State...</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: This would be great but unfortunately the data returned for the parent info just has the sate code.